# How I can make a POST request with Visual Basic to a server that expects a String?

Tags: java, vb.net, post, request, compact-framework

I need to make a POST request in VB.NET to my Tomcat Server with one Java application (made with spring and hibernate) that expects a JSON String. I'm new in VB.NET and I haven't any idea to how to do this.

That's my code in VB.NET (Is an application for smart devices thats so I'm using Compact Framework 3.5)

```
Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    Dim usuario = TextUsuario.Text
    Dim contraseña = TextContraseña.Text

    Dim userCredentials = New Linq.JObject

    If usuario IsNot "" And contraseña IsNot "" Then
        userCredentials.Add("login", usuario)
        userCredentials.Add("password", contraseña)

        Dim userCredentialsJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userCredentials)
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userCredentialsJSON)

        Try
            Dim url = "http://192.168.2.252:7080/SCTraker_Servidor/api/Session"
            Dim httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"

            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            Dim writer As New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            writer.Write(userCredentialsJSON)
            **writer.Close()**

            Dim dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            Dim userJSON = reader.ReadLine

            Dim user = Linq.JObject.Parse(userJSON)
            VariablesGlobales.usuario = user

            If user IsNot "" Then
                Me.Hide()
                AJAXJSON.Show()

            Else
                BarraEstado.Text = "No ha rellenado el campo usuario o contraseña"
            End If
        Catch webException As WebException
            Dim status = webException.Status
            BarraEstado.Text = status + ":" + webException.Message

        Catch socketException As Sockets.SocketException
            BarraEstado.Text = socketException.Message

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

With this, the server returns a Socket Exception in the line with "** **" and it say "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" Error code: 10054

Comment: You are currently telling the server you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.  Which you are not, as far as I can tell, and that is probably why the server is disconnecting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think this would be your whole issue, but I cannot argue with success!

> You are currently telling the server you are sending
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded data. Which you are not, as far as I
>   can tell, and that is probably why the server is disconnecting you.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!